# Javascript: compare against regex or other way

Tags: javascript, regex, compare

I know I can do `/z/i.test(str)` and I can also compare with both `str === z || tre === Z`, just I was curious if there is a short line like this

```
if (str === /z/i) { do the dew }
```

The above line should not check if `str` contains `z|Z` but if it's equal to `z|Z`.

Thank you :)

Comment: Is that really saving that much space over `if(/z/i.test(str)){ do the dew }`?

Comment: It's not that, sorry I forgot to explain, it's because I don't want to check an entire string for `z|Z`, maybe the string has more other stuff, but if the string IS `z|Z`.

Comment: Maybe `if(z.toLowerCase() === 'z'){ do the dew }`? I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you.

Comment: `'zZ'.indexOf(z) >= 0`

Comment: @thednp: It is unclear. Do you want to check if a string *contains* or is *equal* to `z` or `Z`? If the former, I'd suggest `if (z.toLowerCase().indexOf("z") > -1)`. The `/z/i.test(str)` returns true if `str` *contains* `z` or `Z`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated the question, it should check if is equal (`===`) to `z|Z`.

Comment: Then neilsimp's suggestion is correct. Or this `if (z.toUpperCase() === "Z")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript does not have `=~` operator** (like in Perl, Ruby, etc.).

When you write `str === /\n|z/i`, you are comparing a string to a RegExp object, which does not make sense and will yield unexpected results.

The `/z/i.test(str)` returns true if `str` contains `z` or `Z`.

If you need to use a non-regex way to check the same condition, use

```
if (z.toLowerCase().indexOf("z") > -1)
```

If you need to check if the string is *equal* to either `z` or `Z`, you can use

```
if (z.toUpperCase() === "Z")
```

Sample demo:

```js
z = "Zoe"; 
if (z.toLowerCase().indexOf("z") > -1) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "'Z' or 'z' is present in 'Zoe'.<br/>";
}
z = "z"; 
if (z.toUpperCase() === "Z") {
  document.body.innerHTML += "The string  is equal to 'z' or 'Z'";
}
```

Comment: So in conclusion, comparing with a regex isn't working (`str === /\n|z/i`), that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: You are trying to compare a string with a RegExp object that way, it makes no sense. There is just no `=~` operator in JavaScript.